# Statistical test for spatial difference of incidents

Tags: distributions, spatial

I have an area divided into grids. I'm looking for a method to determine statistically, if the occurence of criminal incidents for two time periods is significant equal.

I have two datasets with equal periods and grid locations. The target values are only assigned to a specific time period.

TARGET = 0 -> No incident, TARGET = 1 -> Incident

**Timeperiod 08AM-16PM**
 
Day, XCOR, YCOR, TARGET
1, 1, 1, 0
1, 1, 2, 0 
2, 1, 1, 0
2, 1, 2, 0

**Timeperiod 16PM-24PM**
Day, XCOR, YCOR, TARGET
1, 1, 1, 1
1, 1, 2, 0
2, 1, 1, 0
2, 1, 2, 1

I'm looking for a statistical method to validate/test if the occurence of an incident for both time periods is spatial different?

But, how can I do so?
Any tips, links or advice much appreciated

Comment: How many grid cells do you have? And how large are the cells?

Comment: The current area exists of 50*60 grid cells, all representing an area of 125x125 meters.